# Can I connect a microphone to a valve amp?

Tags: amplifiers, microphones, vacuum-tube

Is it possible/a good idea to plug a mic into a valve amp? I've heard that the output of a mic is too high for it. Anyone know if this is true? Since I don't want to try it out.

Comment: Before the advent of transistor amps, that's the only option we had! It will obviously also depend on the impedance of said mic. But nothing bad will happen . As long as you don't plug it into a speaker output...

Comment: Which particular valve amp?

Comment: Depends on the output impedance of your mike and the input impedance of your amp.  Different models can have different values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with an impedance matching transformer like this one:

https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/LittleIMP--whirlwind-little-imp-lo-z-xlr-to-hi-z-1-4-inch-inline-impedance-matcher

[image]